# Cannot get EditText to display a .setText

Tags: java, android

Can't for the life of me figure out why I can't get this to display in the EditText. I have two classes (java files) set up and this is the second class. Even when I use a simple number (and not a formula) I can't get it to display in the app.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong this time. Any help?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    totalcostEdit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.totaltripcostseditText);
    totallodgingEdit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.totallodgingcostseditText);

}

private void updateStandard ()
{

    //Calculate total lodging costs
    double totallodging = 2;

    totallodgingEdit.setText(String.format("%", totallodging));

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `updateStandard()`?

Comment: I don't know? This is my first time making a second class in Android and I'm completely lost because I think I'm getting a little ahead of my class. Should I post my entire code?

Comment: Try adding it as the last line of your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I'm rather new to coding.

Comment: Oh my god. So I figured out what you meant and switched it to the brackets between OnCreate... it worked!

Comment: Sure, after the line `totallodgingEdit = ...` add a line `updateStandard();`. This will call that method and execute the code inside.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it to work. Usually you don't award the snipers though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not calling `updateStandard()`. Why don't you try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    totalcostEdit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.totaltripcostseditText);
    totallodgingEdit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.totallodgingcostseditText);

    updateStandard();

}

private void updateStandard()
{

    //Calculate total lodging costs
    double totallodging = 2;

    totallodgingEdit.setText(String.valueOf(totallodging));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    totallodgingEdit.setText(totallodging + "");
```

Comment: This didn't work. Much better way to output the setText though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're learning about methods.

When you created `updateStandard()`, that's all you were doing, creating it. Now to actually call it, do the following in your `onCreate` method:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main2);
      totalcostEdit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.totaltripcostseditText);
      totallodgingEdit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.totallodgingcostseditText);
      updateStandard(); // this is the important part
}
```

The reason why `onCreate` is being executed without you calling it anywhere is because it is actually being called somewhere in the Android libraries.